# Can Jersey 2.0 work with Glassfish 2.x?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-2.x, jersey-2.0

I'm using Glassfish v2 (I know it's old).  Now that I've switched to Jersey 2.0, on start up it gives me this exception:

```
 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1578)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1049)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:704)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1649)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1254)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadJ2EEApplicationWebModules(WebContainer.java:1177)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.doLoad(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:141)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.doLoad(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.load(AbstractLoader.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.applicationDeployed(ApplicationManager.java:645)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.invokeApplicationDeployEventListener(AdminEventMulticaster.java:959)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.handleApplicationDeployEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:943)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.processEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.event.AdminEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(AdminEventMulticaster.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.DeploymentNotificationHelper.multicastEvent(DeploymentNotificationHelper.java:308)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentServiceUtils.multicastEvent(DeploymentServiceUtils.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ServerDeploymentTarget.sendStartEvent(ServerDeploymentTarget.java:298)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.ApplicationStartPhase.runPhase(ApplicationStartPhase.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.phasing.DeploymentPhase.executePhase(DeploymentPhase.java:108)
```

Does anyone know why/how it's giving this error?  This isn't the package name used for any jersey code I could find.  Is it possible to use Jersey 2.0 on Glassfish 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to get Jersey 2.0 running on Glassfish 2.x but there was significant renaming of packages from com.sun.jersey -> org.glassfish.jersey from 1.x to 2.x respectively.

It looks like your (web.xml) config is still using the old class names.  What you probably want is something like this:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        ...
    </servlet>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Check out the latest Jersey deployment info [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) for other specifics.